# How to modify incremental project builder of JDT Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to modify the incremental project builder of JDT to add some extra functionality while compiling the java code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can contribute a compilation participant, but how useful you'll find that really depends on just what extra functionality you're trying to add.

http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_jdt_core_compilationParticipant.html?cp=3_1_1_4